# Error on npm -install package.json not found

Tags: npm, installation, visual-studio-code, enoent

Error message:

https://ibb.co/m00A2a -

This is the error I am getting every time and idk how to say this, but some times after 5 min of waiting a node_modules folder is created and I have the library/framework in there and some times it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that has the same error this how you fix it

```
npm install bower -g
```

this installs bower and then in your project folder instead of typing
`npm install jquery` you type `bower install jquery`